# How would I calculate the minimum and maximum wavelength of the Bremsstrahlung released by an electron as it goes through a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electrons

Say, I have an electron gun and ground below it (with a potential difference of U) and two coils side by side between them producing a relatively homogenous magnetic field B. If I shoot an electron laser from the electron gun, how could I calculate the minimum and maximum wavelengths of the Bremsstrahlung (Braking radiation) released from the deflection of electrons due to the magnetic field in relation to U and B?

Note: I am not a phyics student but an engineering student trying to find a suitable sensor for an experiment, so if possible please simplify your explanation. Thank you very much. :)